# Example of Semi-Regular Grammar who's language is NOT regular

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata, language-theory

A "semi-regular" grammar is one that only allows rules of the form:

```
X → y
X → y Y
X → Y y
```

where X and Y are any single non-terminals, and x and y are any single terminals.

For example, this is a semi-regular grammar for language a+ b+

```
S → a S
S → a A
A → A b
A → b
```

Give an example of a semi-regular grammar whose language is NOT a regular language. Be sure to say what the language is and why it is not regular.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
S := aT | -
T := Sb
```

Note that `-` represents the empty string; you could replace this with a single terminal symbol if you like, without changing the regularity. This produces the language `a^n b^n`, the canonical non-regular language. You can easily prove as much using the pumping lemma for regular languages or the Myhill-Nerode theorem.